# How to update track metadata (such as album) on SoundCloud

Tags: soundcloud

I have looked everywhere, but I am not able to find how one is supposed to be able to edit the metadata for a track using the SoundCloud API, see the image below, which is what I'm trying to update via API.

[image]

Im using the Python SoundCloud API, and am able to do this via curl.

Comment: Please read this and reformat your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you're doing this using curl, and what Python code you already have that is failing. Please edit your question to include this.